# Tab index ignored in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, tab, commandbutton, inputtext

This seems such a simple problem, but I cannot see why the solution is not working.

I have an inputText and a command button in the same area of the screen, and want to tab from the inputText to the Command Button. The input text will contain a number of empty records to add, and the command button will run an apex method to add that many.
When I tab from the inputText, however, the cursor travels to the search box at the top of the standard Salesforce header.

How do I force focus onto the Command button?

```
<apex:inputText tabIndex="50" size="3" value="{!addItemNo}" />
<apex:commandButton tabIndex="51" value="Add Rows" action="{!addItems}" rerender="block"/>
```

Comment: If the elements are output exactly as you have them here, there shouldn't be a need to set the tabindex attribute at all: the tab order should naturally follow the order the elements are rendered in the markup. What happens if you remove the tabindex attributes? (See this WebAIM article for reasons to avoid using tabindex http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex .)

Comment: Shannonsans, thanks for the response. I started with no tab indexes - it had exactly the same functionality - that's why I tried to force the order with the tabIndex values.

Comment: Weird... Do you have other markup on the page that's not shown in your example? If you view the page source, does the markup that is generated for your input and button have a tabindex added to it (after removing it from your components).

Comment: Seeing the same thing on my vf page.  The only thing special I note is that my `inputText` and `commandButton` are children of an `outputPanel`, which is in turn the second child of a `pageBlockSectionItem`.  Not sure if this is relevant, but cannot remove the `outputPanel` as `pageBlockSectionItem` only supports 2 children- label and field.

Answer (score 1):

If tabindex does not work, you could catch the focus loss with the onblur event

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_inputText.htm

In that js you can use focus() to set it as you like

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp